# Entity is not api accessible entity name: AccountContactRelation

Tags: apex, unit-test, account, compile-error, accountcontactrelation

While writing a test class I was not able to define object of type `AccountContactRelation` and got error like

> Entity is not api accessible entity name: AccountContactRelation.

However, in apex controller I don't get this kind of error message while creating object or querying records. How can I resolve this compile fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using an `API Version` greater than or equal to **`33.0`**. Any lower version will fail to compile if it references the `AccountContactRelation` object. Although the documentation claims this object was introduced in API Verison 37.0, it seems that the compiler will allow it a little further back. But you might as well use the most up to date version, which is currently **`39.0`**.

Also make sure you enable the feature. Go to `Setup` > `Account Settings` and make sure this option is checked: `Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts`.

> ## [Let Users Relate a Contact to Multiple Accounts](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_shared_contacts_enable.htm)
>
> 1. From Setup, enter Account Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Account Settings.
> 2. Select Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts.
> 3. Add the Related Contacts related list to the account page layouts that your reps use.
>      Because the Related Contacts related list includes all direct contacts, you can remove the Contacts related list from your account page layouts.
>
>    > Easily see who’s a direct contact for the account when you add the Direct field to the Related Contacts related list.
> 4. Add the Related Accounts related list to the contact page layouts your reps use.
>
>    > Easily see which account is the contact’s primary account when you add the Direct field to the Related Accounts related list.
> 5. Decide whether you want to prevent activities from automatically rolling up to a contact’s primary account. If so, from Setup, go to the Activities Setting page and deselect Roll up activities to a contact's primary account.
> 6. If you want to look at the relationships between contacts and accounts, create custom report types.